# Feedback on “Providing support via text forums” task (and related pages) on drupal.org's Contributor Guide

Tags: discussion

As part of the [Getting Involved Guide refresh project](https://www.drupal.org/community/about/getting-involved-guide-becoming-contributor-guide) on drupal.org, we created a “Support” contribution area section and moved a couple of tasks (Provide support on IRC and Provide support on the forums) from the old Getting Involved Guide underneath it.

jhodgdon suggested

- “Provide support via text chat” as a task for contribution to the Drupal community to support people on [Drupal Slack](https://drupal.org/slack), [Drupal Chat](https://drupalchat.me), or another chat-based program.
- “Provide support via text forums” as a task for contribution to the Drupal community to support people on the [forums](https://drupal.org/forum), Drupal Answers, or other post/web-based support web sites.

We created “Provide support via text forums” thinking it was a similar task.

The old content was specific to drupal.org forums. So split the task into two sections, one specific to the forums and the other specific to StackExchange's Q&A format. It may make sense to create a separate “Provide support via Q&A sites” even if asking a question is similar on both the support forums and StackExhange.

Here's the Detailed Steps content as of 2020.07.11:

> For Drupal Forums:
>
> 1. Create a Drupal.org account if you don't already have one, and then log in.
> 2. Navigate to the Support forums page.
> 3. Choose a category that you have some knowledge of, such as Theming or Installing Drupal. Select the category to see a list of questions that have been posted.
> 4. Select the post title of a recent question, and read the post. If you have an answer or can provide useful feedback, select "Add new comment" at the bottom, and add your reply (following the guidelines in the Reference section below).
> 5. Repeat as time permits.
>
> For Drupal Answers:
>
> 1. Navigate to the Drupal Answers web site.
> 2. Create a Stack Exchange account or log in.
> 3. Choose a tag that you have some knowledge of, such as theming or views. Click on the tag to see a list of questions that have been posted.
> 4. Review questions without an accepted answer i.e. an answer that has filled box.
> 5. Select the post title of a recent question without an accepted answer and read the post. Questions without an accepted answer are designated with a filled box. If you have an answer, write Your Answer and post your answer.
>
> - If the question lacks focus or needs additional details, add a comment to the question.
>
> 6. Repeat as time permits.
>
> Note: Drupal Answers is not tied to the Drupal contribution system.

Note that this project has just started on moving content, and there is a lot of documentation regarding how-to write and organize tasks, roles, and skills for the Contributor's guide.

Comment: I would say to the users to select a tag; in the page showing the list of questions using that tag, click on the *Unanswered* tab, which for the *views* tag would show this [page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views?tab=Unanswered). In this way, there isn't any need to explain how to distinguish questions with an accepted answer from the ones without an accepted answer: All the questions in the *Unanswered* tab don't have an accepted answer. (+1 for the initiative.)